# Finding expansions for elements of a group algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Suppose $G$ is a finite group of order $\left|G\right|$, with an associated group algebra $K[G] = \left\{\sum_{g \in G} a_g g\right\}$ over, say, the complex numbers. Suppose we represent $G$, and by linear extension $K[G]$, as  operators on some $d$-dimensional complex vector space $V$, according to some representation $D$.

If   $\left|G\right|> 2d^2$, the  representations $D(g)$ of each group element cannot all be linearly independent operators. Therefore, given $k \in K[G]$, its representative $D(k)$ will not have a unique expansion in terms of the $D(g)$.

My question is then:

i) is there a way to determine a complete, LI set of $D(g)$ exclusively from the properties of $G$, $D$ and of the irreps of $G$? (by which I mean that I wish to avoid cumbersome orthonormalization procedures such as Gram-Schmidt). 
Equivalently, given a particular operator $M \in D[K]$, is there a group-theoretic way of finding a valid expansion for $M$ in terms of $D(g)$?

ii) More ambitiously, is there a systematic way of finding the *shortest* possible expansion for $M$ (ie, the one involving the fewest number of different $g$?